# AvalonEdit how to add new syntax in converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, avalonedit, avaloniaui

I want to add custom highlight in converter and a new syntax (JSON) but, keep using MVVM etc...

That means, I must not go this way:

```
editor.HighLight = HightLightLoader.Load()
```

I tried to set my logic in a convertor, but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this task?

```cs
public class HighlightingDefinitionConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter Converter = new HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var json = value as string;
            if (json.Equals("JSON"))
            {
                var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader("JSONHighLight.xshd");
                return Converter.ConvertFrom(xmlTextReader);
            }

            return Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Converter.ConvertToString(value);
        }
    }
```

My xshd file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SyntaxDefinition name="JSON" extensions=".js" xmlns="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/syntaxdefinition/2008">
    <Color name="Digits" foreground="#8700FF" exampleText="3.14" />
    <Color name="Value" foreground="#000CFF" exampleText="var text = &quot;Hello, World!&quot;;" />
    <Color name="ParamName" foreground="#057500"  exampleText="var text = &quot;Hello, World!&quot;;" />
    <RuleSet ignoreCase="false">
        <Keywords color="Digits" >
            <Word>true</Word>
            <Word>false</Word>
        </Keywords>
        <Span color="ParamName">
            <Begin>"</Begin>
            <End>(?=:)</End>
        </Span>
        <Span color="Value" multiline="true">
            <Begin>
                (?&lt;=:)\040"[^"]*
            </Begin>
            <End>"</End>
        </Span>
        <Rule color="Digits">\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|(\b\d+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?</Rule>
    </RuleSet>
</SyntaxDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxHighlighting` property expects an object that implements `IHighlightingDefinition` interface. You are trying to get on from built-in `HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter`, but it [tries to look up one by name](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/AvaloniaEdit/blob/0526f81fe654c7a6a34cf247d6a893406734dfc9/src/AvaloniaEdit/Highlighting/HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter.cs#L41), so passing it XmlTextReader won't work.

An example of code that loads syntax from stream can be found [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/AvaloniaEdit/blob/master/src/AvaloniaEdit/Highlighting/HighlightingManager.cs#L237):

```
using (var s = Resources.OpenStream(resourceName))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(s))
{    
    var xshd = HighlightingLoader.LoadXshd(reader, true);
    return HighlightingLoader.Load(xshd, this);
}
```